# How to make another api call after finishing of concatMap

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to make an API call after my concatMap is finished.

```
from(array)
        .pipe(
           concatMap(el => return APICall(el))
        )
        .subscribe(
           response => { 
            if(!(response instanceof HttpErrorResponse)) {
              responses.push(response);
            }
          }
        )
```

How can I wait untill concatMap finish working and then do other API calls?

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe in a `switchMap` (or a `concatMap`) inside the outer `concatMap`.

```js
from(array).pipe(
  concatMap(el => return APICall(el).pipe(
    switchMap(el2 => return OtherApiCall(el2))
  ))
).subscribe(
  response => { 
    if(!(response instanceof HttpErrorResponse)) {
      responses.push(response);
    }
  }
);
```

#### Update: wait for all `concatMap` to complete

```js
forkJoin(
  array.map(el => APICall(el))
).pipe(
  switchMap(res =>        // <-- here `res` would be an array of all responses from the array
    OtherApiCall()
  )
).subscribe(...);
```

#### Update 2: wait for all sequential requests to complete

There isn't a direct way to execute something after all the sequential requests using `from`+`concatMap`. You could however use `toArray` operator to collect all the responses and emit it as an array similar to the `forkJoin`'s output. This would essentially halt the workflow until all the responses are collected.

```js
from(array).pipe(
  concatMap(el => return APICall(el)),
  toArray(),
  switchMap(res =>         // <-- here `res` would be an array of all responses from the array
    return OtherApiCall()
  )
).subscribe(
  response => { 
    if(!(response instanceof HttpErrorResponse)) {
      responses.push(response);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I would like to wait when all requests finish their work.
For example, array consists of 4 elemnts and I want to wait untill these 4 requests finish their work and then make other API calls

Comment: In that case you could use `forkJoin` with `Array#map` function. I've updated the answer.

Comment: For first part of the comment why redo a pipe on the API call and not do a `switchMap` after `concatMap` in the first pipe?

Comment: @Substitut: It's only a matter of aesthetics. Both would work virtually identically.

Comment: But if I use fokJoin won`t these request execute in parallel mode? I need execute them one by one.

Comment: @YehorPavlenko: You could use a workaround using `toArray` operator. I've updated the answer.